Importing images to use as icons within a react.js project
I have an index.js that imports images to use as icons in a verticaltimeline component (from react.js) that showcases my work experience. This project is followed by a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fYi8SGA20k) where in the file they provided all the images are imported fine. However, when I try and add my own image into the same asset file and call it I get this error:
SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/assets/index.js' does not provide an export named 'whittleburypark' (at index.js:26:5)
Here is the import code:
import {
    mobile,
    backend,
    creator,
    web,
    javascript,
    typescript,
    html,
    css,
    reactjs,
    redux,
    tailwind,
    nodejs,
    mongodb,
    git,
    figma,
    docker,
    meta,
    starbucks,
    tesla,
    shopify,
    carrent,
    jobit,
    tripguide,
    threejs, 
    whittleburypark, // this is my image i have added
  } from "../assets";

Here is the code where it is being used
const experiences = [
    {
      title: "Digital Marketing Assistant",
      company_name: "Whittlebury Park",
      icon: whittleburypark, //if i use for example 'starbucks' it works fine
      iconBg: "#383E56",
      date: "June 2019 - July 2019",
      points: [
        "I spent the summer of 2019 working as a Digital Marketing Assistant. It was an exciting and insightful experience as during this time I was heavily involved in the preparation for the Silverstone F1 Grand Prix. ",
        "Working within a small team, I developed branding material for the event and led on providing social media content.",
        " Throughout this busy and challenging period, I learnt plenty of skills that gave me great insight into digital marketing world.",
      ],
    },

The file 'whittleburypark.png' is in the same directory as 'starbucks.png' and the rest of the images, where it is being fetched from ../assets.
I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I understand this is within a larger project so if you need anymore information please let me know.

Make the following changes in the "assets/index.js" file.
First, import the image.
import whittleburypark from "./company/whittleburypark.png";

Then you need to export it along with the other exports.
export{
//other exports 
whittleburypark
};

The above code is based on the project's GitHub repository. I used the "./company/whittleburypark.png" path as you mentioned that it is located in the same directory as "starbucks.png".

Thankyou, this worked. Silly of me to miss out checking "assets/index.js" completely.
